# New thread for every TcpCLient - or what is way to get 100+ clients

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I write WPF application. What is app do its - Just listen data from gps tracker.

Problem is - I dont know how handle 100+ devices. I mean - now I do like:

```
 {
    var serviceIP = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("sericeIP");
    var servicePort = Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("sericePort"));
    var dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
    IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse(serviceIP);
    _client = new TcpListener(localAddr, servicePort);
    _client.Start();
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = _client.AcceptTcpClient();
            new Thread(() => AcceptClient(tcpClient, dispatcher)).Start();
        }
    });
}

private void AcceptClient(TcpClient client, Dispatcher dispatcher)
{
    client.ReceiveTimeout = 13000;
    while (client.Connected)
    {
        try
        {
            NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
            string dataReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            // My logic
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {  }
    }
}
```

For 1 device its OK - but now I think what will be with 100 - 500-1000 devices.........1000 thread will kill machine - so I dont know what way is better for listen big count of devices

Answer (score 1):

You need to use asynchronous programming. There are several articles that will help you do that. MSDN got an [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx) for instance. With async, you do not need to allocate threads yourself. .NET takes care of that. And all threads are freed when the OS is waiting on IO operations. Thus a much smaller number of threads can handle your connections.

If you are going to receive data from 1000 devices, why are you doing it in a client application? What should the devices do when the WPF application is closed?

It's much better to receive the information in a windows service and store the information in a  database. In that way you can also go back and to analysis on all received information.

Comment: OK thank you for tip about service. will check it. and thgank you for async ;)